# Concatenate in SQL and then use in Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, subquery, left-join

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT a.*,CONCAT(b.FirstName, " ", b.LastNameNoSuffix) AS Concatenate, b.*

  FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] a

  Left Join [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] b
  on b.Concatenate= a.[display_name]
```

But I am getting an `Invalid column name` error

Hopefully its something simple but I cannot seem to work it out?
Thanks!

Comment: Use the concat in the join, rather than the aliased name - it won't resolve the alias until the join is processed!

Comment: [Logical processing order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement): "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses" (`JOIN` is step 3)

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, like `' '`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, so `" "` is a column name here.)

Comment: If you do need to join on a name, and in one table it separates them and the other it doesn't, then you probably want to consider the design as well. Storing a name in it's separate parts is always the way to go, but you can always add a (`PERSISTED`) computed column to the table that concatenates them as well for ease. Adding that column to your table aliased `b` would enable to you `JOIN` trivially to the table `a`.

Comment: From experience though, a name is a poor `JOIN` candidate/identifier. There used to be someone who lived a few doors down from me that shared both the same name and DoB, as as we lived near by the addresses were very similar. It always took my local doctor and dentist a while to work out which of us they were speaking to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do what you need:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM test a
join (select t2.*
             , CONCAT(t2.FirstName, ' ', t2.lastname) AS Concatenate
      from test2 t2) b on b.Concatenate = a.[display_name]
```

And here is a small demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32c88657fa888c352ab190b5a0578243)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Concatenate in your `LEFT JOIN`, you can do it like following using a SUB SELECT or a `CTE` function

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.*
        ,CONCAT (
            t.FirstName
            ,' '
            ,t.lastname
            ) AS Concatenate
    FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[yyyyy] t
    ) b ON b.Concatenate = a.[display_name]
```

**Note**: If  you are using SQL Server, use single quote instead of double quotes in your `CONCAT` function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reuse an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in the same scope (left apart the `ORDER BY` clause). You can either use a subquery (which creates a new scope), or repeat the expression. I find that the computation is simple enough so the second solution is good enough:

```
select a.*, b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastnamenosuffix as concatenate, b.*
from a
left join b on b.firstname + ' ' b.lastnamenosuffix = a.display_name
```

Notes:

- don't use double quotes for literal strings! Use single quotes only, as specified in standard SQL
- SQL Server supports `+` for string concatenation, which shortens the expression a little

Answer (score 0):

Use a `VALUES()` clause and `CROSS APPLY`.  It is pretty much designed for this:

```
SELECT a.*, v.Concatenate, b.*
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] a LEFT JOIN
     ([xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] b CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES (CONCAT(b.FirstName, ' ', b.LastNameNoSuffix))
      ) v(concatenate)
     ) 
     ON v.Concatenate = a.[display_name]
```